# Closing external process in CompletableFuture chain

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I'm looking for better way to "close" some resource, here destroy external `Process`, in `CompletableFuture` chain. Right now my code looks roughly like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<ExecutionContext> createFuture()
{
    final Process[] processHolder = new Process[1];
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> {
                try {
                    processHolder[0] = new ProcessBuilder(COMMAND)
                            .redirectErrorStream(true)
                            .start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
                return PARSER.parse(processHolder[0].getInputStream());
            }, SCHEDULER)
            .applyToEither(createTimeoutFuture(DURATION), Function.identity())
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                processHolder[0].destroyForcibly();
                if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
                    throw new DatasourceTimeoutException(throwable);
                }
                Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf(throwable, DatasourceException.class);
                throw new DatasourceException(throwable);
            });
}
```

The problem I see is a "hacky" one-element array which holds reference to the process, so that it can be closed in case of error. Is there some `CompletableFuture` API which allows to pass some "context" to `exceptionally` (or some other method to achieve that)?

I was considering custom `CompletionStage` implementation, but it looks like a big task to get rid of "holder" variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to have linear chain of `CompletableFuture`s. Well actually, you already haven’t due to the `createTimeoutFuture(DURATION)` which is quite convoluted for implementing a timeout. You can simply put it this way:

```
public CompletableFuture<ExecutionContext> createFuture() {
    CompletableFuture<Process> proc=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () -> {
            try {
                return new ProcessBuilder(COMMAND).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }, SCHEDULER);
    CompletableFuture<ExecutionContext> result
        =proc.thenApplyAsync(process -> PARSER.parse(process.getInputStream()), SCHEDULER);
    proc.thenAcceptAsync(process -> {
        if(!process.waitFor(DURATION, TimeUnit.WHATEVER_DURATION_REFERS_TO)) {
            process.destroyForcibly();
            result.completeExceptionally(
                new DatasourceTimeoutException(new TimeoutException()));
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

If you want to keep the timout future, perhaps you consider the process startup time to be significant, you could use

```
public CompletableFuture<ExecutionContext> createFuture() {
    CompletableFuture<Throwable> timeout=createTimeoutFuture(DURATION);
    CompletableFuture<Process> proc=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () -> {
            try {
                return new ProcessBuilder(COMMAND).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }, SCHEDULER);
    CompletableFuture<ExecutionContext> result
        =proc.thenApplyAsync(process -> PARSER.parse(process.getInputStream()), SCHEDULER);
    timeout.exceptionally(t -> new DatasourceTimeoutException(t))
           .thenAcceptBoth(proc, (x, process) -> {
                if(process.isAlive()) {
                    process.destroyForcibly();
                    result.completeExceptionally(x);
                }
            });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: First snippet I cannot use, because `.waitFor` blocks and I want to consume possibly very big `InputStream` (hence `.redirectErrorStream(true)`, I have "error detection" later, but that's another story). The second way seems a bit convoluted (3 futures, including `CompletableFuture<Throwable>`), but I'll give it a try.

Comment: It blocks in an *asynchronous* operation. That’s the whole point of `thenAcceptAsync` or well, `CompleteableFuture` stages in general; independent stages can run concurrently. Here, `PARSER.parse` and `process.waitFor` run in independent stages at the same time.

Comment: Ah, I see. Let's try `waitFor` then!

Comment: @Holger, with the first way, you're blocking a timeout thread for each call to `createFuture`. If you implement `createTimeoutFuture` in terms of either `Timer` or a single instance of a `ScheduledExecutorService`', you use a dedicated set of threads, probably just one, to handle timeouts.  The second way is plain wrong, because 1) you're using `exceptionally` on the timeout future, and 2) if `proc` throws an exception, the continuation set up by `.thenAcceptBoth` completes exceptionally as well and won't run.

Comment: @acelent: blocking a background thread is not a problem per se, you can have thousands of blocked threads without any performance impact. If it really becomes a performance issue, an alternative solution using a thread pool is needed, otherwise, it’s just premature optimization. Further, the original code clearly suggests that the timeout future will complete exceptionally after the time elapsed. Hence, using `exceptionally` on it is the right thing. There might be room for improvements, anyway, it’s meant to demonstrate that the logic can be modeled without single item arrays, nothing more.

Comment: @Holger, I agree with everything else you say, but in my experience, saving threads is not a case of premature optimization.  We don't know if this is a one-shot or a utility, its expected usage, etc., but it's really so easy to use `Timer` instead of a thread per call that it warrants using a promise `CompletableFuture` instead of a computation one that blocks.  Blocking threads from the global `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` has an impact, not necessarily due to the number of used threads, but because it's a shared global resource.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the one item array myself to emulate what would be proper closures in Java.

Another option is using a private static class with fields.  The advantages are that it makes the purpose clearer and has a bit less impact on the garbage collector with big closures, i.e. an object with N of fields versus N arrays of length 1.  It also becomes useful if you need to close over the same fields in other methods.

This is a *de facto* pattern, even outside the scope of `CompletableFuture` and it has been (ab)used long before lambdas were a thing in Java, e.g. anonymous classes.  So, don't feel so bad, it's just that Java's evolution didn't provide us with proper closures (yet? ever?).

If you want, you may return values from `CompletableFuture`s inside `.handle()`, so you can wrap the completion result in full and return a wrapper.  In my opinion, this is not any better than manual closures, added the fact that you'll create such wrappers per future.

Subclassing `CompletableFuture` is not necessary.  You're not interested in altering its behavior, only in attaching data to it, which you can do with current Java's final variable capturing.  That is, unless you profile and see that creating these closures is actually affecting performance somehow, which I highly doubt.